# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::isDeferred()

Tags: laravel-5, facade, laravel-facade

I am try to run any php artisan commend in my project but i can't every time try i find this error als when i try to load

```
    In ProviderRepository.php line 149:
    
      Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::isDeferred()

Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

i don't know what happen i define database in config file and also at AppServiceProvider as a following

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;//to define class schema

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Schema :: defaultStringLength(191);  //add when php artisan migrate pass error after used defult auth
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

and i am use php and laravel version:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "laraform/laraform-laravel": "^1.2",
    "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
},
```